# VBA to delete rows, once specified keywords are found

Tags: excel, vba

Following on from this question, [VBA wildcards or partial matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004996/vba-wildcards-or-partial-matches?noredirect=1#comment75047956_44004996)

As requested, and for the benefit of others.

User Flephal provided the code at the bottom of this text.

The code searches a list of keywords and deletes all columns that do not contain these keywords.

The last part of the problem is to now modify this code so that it will delete any rows above the row containing the keywords The keywords are always on the same row.
For example, if the Keywords are on row 5, then rows 1 to 4 need to be deleted, so the keywords are now on row 1.

I need this as I have other formula on another sheet that relies on the keywords being found in `ROW(1:1)` of the sheet that is being modified by the below code.

```
    Sub RemoveExtraCols()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weights")
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = ActiveSheet

    Dim KeyWords() As String
    Dim Temp As Range, FoundRange As Range, i As Long

    With wsSrc
        ' SrcRange should be a single contiguous row or column
        Dim SrcRange As Range: Set SrcRange = .Range(.Cells(5, 37), .Cells(17, 37))
    End With

    With wsDest
        Dim SearchRange As Range: Set SearchRange = wsDest.UsedRange
    End With

    KeyWords = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(SrcRange), "#"), "#")

    For i = 0 To UBound(KeyWords)
        If KeyWords(i) <> "" Then
            Set Temp = FindAll(KeyWords(i), SearchRange, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
                Set FoundRange = Temp
            Else
                If Not Temp Is Nothing Then Set FoundRange = Application.Union(FoundRange, Temp)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    For i = SearchRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Temp = Application.Intersect(SearchRange.Columns(i), FoundRange)
        If Temp Is Nothing Then
            SearchRange.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it

```
Sub RemoveExtraCols()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weights")
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = ActiveSheet
    Dim nRow As Long
    Dim KeyWords() As String
    Dim Temp As Range, FoundRange As Range, i As Long

    With wsSrc
        ' SrcRange should be a single contiguous row or column
        Dim SrcRange As Range: Set SrcRange = .Range(.Cells(5, 37), .Cells(17, 37))
    End With

    With wsDest
        Dim SearchRange As Range: Set SearchRange = wsDest.UsedRange
    End With

    KeyWords = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(SrcRange), "#"), "#")

    For i = 0 To UBound(KeyWords)
        If KeyWords(i) <> "" Then
            Set Temp = FindAll(KeyWords(i), SearchRange, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
                Set FoundRange = Temp
            Else
                If Not Temp Is Nothing Then Set FoundRange = Application.Union(FoundRange, Temp)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        nRow = FoundRange(1).Row
        Range("A1").Resize(nRow - 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If

    For i = SearchRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Temp = Application.Intersect(SearchRange.Columns(i), FoundRange)
        If Temp Is Nothing Then
            SearchRange.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: "91: Object variable or With black variable not set" on `nRow = Temp.Row`

Comment: Are these items all found on the sheet?

Comment: It is a list of keywords, some may be present, others may not. All may be present or even none.

Comment: Code above amended.

Comment: Thanks, it then brought up error if the first row is already the row containing the keywords.  I added an extra `IF` to say `If nRow <> 1 Then` and it now appears to be correct. Thanks!